# How do I capture events from dijit/Editor?

Tags: javascript, dojo, rich-text-editor

I set up a field for dijit/Editor and I'd like to capture events that occur on this field:

```
<label for="eed-event-description" class="required">Event Description</label><br />
<div id="eed-event-description" data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" height="120px" title="required: brief description of what someone attending can expect at the event" required>
<p></p>
</div>
```

As suggested by Boo Berr'ita ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502222/how-do-i-get-the-contents-from-dijit-editor/50505413?noredirect=1#comment88063353_50505413)), I'm able to get the contents with:

```
var myEditor = registry.byId("eed-event-description");
var htmlValue = myEditor.get("value");
```

Now, I want to capture the onpaste event. I tried setting up on(), but I don't know how to reference the field. For example:

```
on(dom.byId("eed-event-description"), "paste", function () {
}
```

does not trigger.

I've looked in detail at the on() and registry() documentation, plus the widget events reference, but I don't see any way to capture the paste event.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

look at the below link for the available events for dijit/editor

https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/Editor

paste event that you referring is not available by default. But you can use some the extra plug-in for that. Refer to the below link

https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/editor/plugins/SafePaste

you can get more information on SafePaste @

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/editor/plugins/SafePaste.html

Comment: Manjunatha, that is very helpful. I might want to use SafePaste for this, and it has an onBlur() listed in the Events section. But I don't know how to link this onBlur() to the editor. The example at https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/Editor doesn't reference the editor or onBlur. So, if I added SafePaste to my editor and I wanted to get the value of the editor when it lost focus, what do you think I should do? I think this is on the right track, and I'd appreciate your advice. Thanks!

Comment: I did notice one place where it looks like they've added an event handler as a parameter inside data-dojo-props. Something like: data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){console.log('message)}". Perhaps that's how I can connect to at least the editor events.

Comment: Yes you can do that way. Let me know if you need a working example of Editor I will try to get one for you.

Comment: I tested onChange() in data-dojo-props and it does call the console.log() function. But, I decided not to use it because I can do the processing when the form is submitted. I think I could put a call to a private function in the onChange body, but I really want to use features from dojo, and I'm not sure how to make a call to a function that's within the dojo require scope. However, using SafePaste and some fix-up is good enough for now. Thank you for your help, Manjunatha!

Answer (score 0):

to capture the paste event. you  can just use something like  :

```
on(target, type, function (event) {    
    // your code    
});
```